# What does it mean by " ans += (a[i] - ans * r > 0); ", where ans,r are integers and a[i] is an array element?

Tags: c++

i cant understand the second line of the below code:

```
for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   ans += (a[i] - ans * r > 0);
   printf("%d\n", ans);
}
```

Comment: With https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence you will see that `(a[i] - ans * r > 0)` is equivalent to `(((a[i]) - (ans * r)) > 0)`. The value of `(a[i]) - (ans * r)` is compared with `0`. The result is converted to the type of `ans`. If it's a numeric type: true => 1, false => 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, simplify.

Due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the line

```
ans += (a[i] - ans * r > 0);
```

is equivalent to:

```
ans += ((a[i] - ans * r) > 0);
```

To make it more readable, use:

```
bool temp1 = ((a[i] - ans * r) > 0);
ans += temp1;
```

When used in a term such as `ans += temp1`, a `bool` gets converted/promoted to `1` if the value is `true` and to `0` if the value is `false`.

A further simplification would be:

```
bool temp1 = ((a[i] - ans * r) > 0);
int temp2 = (temp1? 1 : 0);
ans += temp2;
```

In the end, `ans` gets incremented by `1` if `(a[i] - ans * r) > 0`. Otherwise, its value remains unchanged.